# Do I need to install `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` if I'm not doing front-end development

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php

In [this section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer) of the `yii2` installation guide there's the following instructions:

> With Composer installed, you can install Yii by running the following
>   commands under a Web-accessible folder:
>
> `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"`
>
> `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic`
>
> The first command installs the composer asset plugin which allows managing bower and npm package dependencies through Composer.

I've read about `composer-asset-plugin` [here](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/) and seems that it's used to manage front-end dependencies through composer. As I'm not developing for front-end, do I need to install this plugin anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Do you need to use this package? Do you get some error while not using it?

Comment: I don't to use it just because it's listed in the installation doc, I want to understand why I'd need it and in my case of solely server side development whether I need it all

Comment: I'd try both options and see what happens. Nothing bad happens when you install the asset plugin. It only helps to install assets, that are required by Yii.

Comment: Well, thanks, I'll wait maybe someone knows for sure

Comment: What prevents you from running these commands by yourself?

Comment: Nothing, but I want explanation instead of just knowing `works/doesn't work`

Comment: I think Yii forum is the right place to do so: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do I was not able to install specific version of extension because of not installing it and it was solved after installing it. More details on this link [Yii Framework forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68692-extension-installation-installation-of-asset-plugin/page__gopid__292289#entry292289)

Comment: actually it is not required, it depends on what you're are planning to use YII for. For more details, see my topic [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68361-do-i-need-to-install-fxpcomposer-asset-plugin-if-im-not-doing-front-end-development/page__view__findpost__p__290882)

Comment: You are right!!! some extensions can be used without it but some need it to install other things they lack

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have to. Else you can't install Yii.

```
yiisoft/yii2 requires bower-asset/jquery *@stable -> no matching package found.
```

Comment: If you remove the views and related *Assets, the dependency can also be removed. In your example a simple `git cloner` `composer install` it will indeed require the bower (and thus fxp) dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

Correction: As per ./vendor/yiisoft/yii2/composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "bower-asset/jquery": "2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable",
    ...
}
```

`fxp` is, sadly, required. PR submitted to project https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14265

Project owner has also stated here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68361-do-i-need-to-install-fxpcomposer-asset-plugin-if-im-not-doing-front-end-development/page__p__290882#entry290882 that the fxp requirement will be removed in release 2.1

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try
[yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip)

---

In Yii2 composer.json, require yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip before yiisoft/yii2.

Example composer.json:

```json
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip": "~2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0"
}
```